# Не работает click у добавляемого div элемента

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

По нажатию на грань куба вызывается слой #cubiSheet, который автоматически заполняется деревом элементов по средством метода html. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы красная вверху кнопка срабатывала на нажатия. Она никак не реагирует, однако ховер работает. Можете подсказать, что не правильно? Ошибок в консоле нет.
[image: Код]

[image: View]

Comment: для динамических элементов используется делегированная обработка событий

Comment: Не сработало... Вот пример:
$("#cubikSheet").click((event)=>{
    let target = event.target;
    if(target.className == "closeCube"){
        alert("+++");
    }
});

Comment: `cubikSheet` - у вас в разметке это клас, а здесь используете как id

Comment: Это суперэлемент. Как вы и сказали делегировать событие. Но он не видит в нем элементов...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

попробуйте добавить `event listener`

```
$("body").on('click', '.closeCube', function(){
    alert('this is click!')
})
```

Comment: Помогло. Правда вы малость напутали элементы. но смысл я понял. Только не понял почему этот вариант заработал)))

Comment: Ваш код 
$("#cubikSheet").click((event)=>{ let target = event.target; if(target.className == "closeCube"){ alert("+++"); } });
срабатывает в момент загрузки страницы, когда этого элемента ещё нет на странице

Comment: Блин вы наверное правы. надо попробовать таймер еще присобачить... спс

Comment: А почему этот вариант сработал ваш? Можете пояснить пжлст?

Comment: @GlebIgorevich https://api.jquery.com/on/ пункт **Direct and delegated event handlers**

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял.